# mavros catkin_build error

Tags: catkin-make, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , I followed the steps on ROS wiki about mavros to install .

But I don't know why it can't be compiled suddenly .

Could anyone give me a hand? thank you!!

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239825/mavros-catkin_build-error/) by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not find installation instructions in the wiki. I found them in [git](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md#installation). There is a debian package available. So, you can run the following command to get it installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-mavros ros-jade-mavros-extras
```

Replace `jade` with the name of whatever ros distribution you are using. . The git also says how to install from the source, if you are particular about getting it installed that way.

---

Originally posted by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) with karma: 178 on 2016-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on 2016-07-19**:
I mark all the error source code than it can works again.(Only this way)

But I still don't know why it couldn't be complied.

Thanks for your reply :)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-07-21**:
If this answer resolves your issue, please mark it as accepted (with a green check mark).

If you still need to build it from source, is the git documentation enough?

**Comment by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on 2016-07-21**:
Ok, thanks for your remind. I tried the git documentation but it was not the resource.